# Problem with multiprocessing Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, multiprocessing

I want to open the same sites in multiprocessing (and use specific chrome profiles). But after running the code, it opens chrome profiles but open link only on one.
Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from multiprocessing import Pool
import selenium.common.exceptions
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Skitrow\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")

service = Service(r'C:\Users\Skitrow\PycharmProjects\bot\chromedriver.exe')




profiles_names = [11, 1, 2, 3, 4] # Here is names of profiles
def get_data(profiles_func):
    url = 'https://google.com'
    options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile " + str(profiles_func))

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(processes=5)
    p.map(get_data, profiles_names)
```

I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: hi did you find a solution? i share the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

Back when I tried to implement multiprocessing I had a very rough time as well, I solved it using [seleniumbase](https://seleniumbase.io/) and would recommend you to check it out, you can specify how many threads you want to run the script in from the CLI and it has a ton of other great features that will speed up your workflow.

Comment: How i can realize multiprocessing with this framework?

Comment: For example if you're using pytest you can attach the "-n=4" flag when starting your tests to decide how many threads to use, you can find more information [here](https://seleniumbase.io/help_docs/customizing_test_runs/#seleniumbase-features)